# Pass ArrayList from Activity to ListFragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to implement a fragment layout.  I have an activity that servers as a SplashScreen & fetches some data from the web and creates an ArrayList of my custom objects.

Normally If I were using a ListView I would just do the following.

```
private ArrayList<Articles> articles;

private void isComplete() {
         Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, ListActivity.class);
         intent.putExtra("data", articles);
         startActivity(intent);
         finish();
    }
```

How can I do pass the same data to a Fragment?  Your help I much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its simple take Global class 
And `declare public static ArrayList<Articles> articles = new ArrayList<Articles>;`
In main Activity `Global.articles = articles` ;
Now u can use any where in Project.

Comment: Thanks it worked but static variables take space in memory!! any other way possible??

Comment: @Nischal yes you can for ref http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14997855/pass-the-arraylist-with-particular-id-from-one-class-to-another-in-android

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the type of arraylist

- putIntegerArrayListExtra(String name, ArrayList value)
- putParcelableArrayListExtra(String name, ArrayList value)
- putStringArrayListExtra(String name, ArrayList value)
- putCharSequenceArrayListExtra(String name, ArrayList value)

Then you can read from you next activity by replacing put with get with key string as argument,eg

```
myIntent.getStringArrayListExtra("arrayPeople");
```

Answer (score -2):

use putExtra to pass value to an intent. use getSerializableExtra method to retrieve the data

If I have two activities A and B I want to pass ArrayList> value to Activity B then I will use the following code in class A

**Pass ArrayList> data from Activity A to Activity B**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class);
HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
hm.put("sunil", "sahoo");
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arl = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
arl.add(hm);
intent.putExtra("arraylist", arl);
startActivityForResult(intent, 500);
```

**Retrieve the value in Activity B**

In class B i will write the folowing code to retrieve the data

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arl =(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("arraylist");
System.out.println("...serialized data.."+arl);
```

Comment: Question is about ListFragment. Not about Activity.