# Pass the arraylist with particular id from one class to another in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, arraylist

I want to pass the data from one class to another by passing the arraylist with id ..

```
 listviewfirst.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Intent i= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Questionactivity.class);
                    // To pass data 
                   i.putExtra("uploadarraylist", uploadarraylist);
                   startActivity(i);


        }
```

Here I have pass the array list, but based on id no I want to pass the data to next activity page.

Comment: I think you can't send any arraylist in intent's extra. Make your arraylist common so that it can be used in any class. And instead of passing arraylist in extra put clicked item's index(arg2) and fetch particular index values from your array in any class.

Comment: @user370305 suppose i have store question id in arraylist and based on question id i want to pass to the next view .

Comment: @user370305 yes..i need to pass the question id with arraylist based on question id i will get the data from arraylist ,am i clear

Comment: do 1 thing sangita just put a method in one class which has the arraylist and call that method from another activity to get all items based on id??

Comment: @user370305 yes..right..how could i do that

Comment: @user370305  its ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> uploadarraylist

Comment: are you using sqlitedatabase also????

Comment: @Shiv only webservice..json parse..

Comment: @user370305 it work like if will click 3rd question its displaying from the first ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have `ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> uploadarraylist`

And you want to pass particular `HashMap` for given selected index to next Activity then,

```
listviewfirst.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
         HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = uploadarraylist.get(arg2);
         Intent i= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Questionactivity.class);
         // To pass data                 
         i.putExtra("hashMap", hashMap);
         startActivity(i);
        }
```

And in **Questionactivity**

```
Intent intent = getIntent();    
HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = (HashMap<String, Object>) intent.getSerializableExtra("hashMap");
```

Comment: but i have store question id inside the arraylist,..is it work\

Comment: NO its works as same..if click 3rd question it is displaying from first only

Comment: Means?? I didn't get you. Actually what type of Object is?

Comment: You can get object by `hashmap.get("<String_Key>");`

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the array list values through Bundle.

```
>           Intent i= new Intent(context, QuestionActivity.class); 
>           Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
> 
>           bundle.putStringArrayList("messages", book_mark);
>           bundle.putIntegerArrayList("cell_ids", cell_ids);
>           bundle.putIntegerArrayList("cat_ids", cat_ids);
>           bundle.putIntegerArrayList("bkmId", bkmId); 
>           bookmark.putExtras(bundle);             
>           startActivity(i);
```

Comment: i have single array list where i have stored the question ids ,question and based on id i want to pass to the next class..is it clear..

Comment: You have multiple questions with id's in arraylist right?  So, you can get question number and set to the arraylist elements based on index number using setId() method. After that you can able to fetch that question id's from getId(). I hope you can understand my words.

Comment: yes..do you know pass object inside text view like textview.settext(object); is it possible

Answer (score 0):

Make that arrayList as static list and then use it on another class by using declared calss reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this as given below, so after that there is no need to pass via Intent:

You may declare your ArrayList as a static one like this:

```
public static ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
```

By doing this you can access your ArrayList from any Activity by:

```
activityname.array;
```

where activityname is the activity or class in which you declare the static ArrayList.

Or if you want to use intent than you can do this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,activityname.class);
Bundle bun = new Bundle();
bun.putIntegerArrayListExtra(String name, ArrayList<Integer> value);
//bun.putParcelableArrayListExtra(String name, ArrayList<? extends Parcelable> value);
//bun.putStringArrayListExtra(String name, ArrayList<String> value);
i.putExtra(String name,bun);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an arraylist such as:
     `ArrayList<YourClass> list;`
Make your class implement the  Serializable interface.
After that you can add your arraylist in the putExtra() method.

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Bicycle implements Serializable{

  public int speed;

  public Bicycle(int startSpeed) {
    speed = startSpeed;
  }        
}
```

And in your activity:

```
ArrayList<Bicycle> list = new ArrayList<Bicycle>();
Intent i = new intent(currentActivity.this, nextActivity.class);
i.putExtra("array", list);
startActivity(i);
```