# How to send the array data from one activity to fragment in android?

Tags: android, arrays, android-fragments

I am building an android application where an user select their favorite stuff.

The name of stuff is added in an array  when user clicks on the stuff's image.

Now I want to know how can I parse the value of that array to any fragment and show it in my spinner list.

For example: user select Mobile and tablet by clicking on respective images then these values added in to an array name 'stuffarray' now I want to pass this array to my fragment on an 'submitted' button and when I click on an spinner of my fragment it Should have mobile and tablet value in there list.

Here is my code for stuff selection :

```
submite = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.nextscreen);      
next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Intent innext = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivitytabnew.class);

        startActivity(innext);              

});
img1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);


img1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mobile);   
img1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         isClicked1=!isClicked1;
            if (isClicked1) {
                img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.mobile);
                start();
                stuff1 = "mobile";

                   myList.add(stuff1);



            }else {
                img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.mobile);
                myList.remove(sport1);
                //sport1 = "";  
                txt1.setText("");
            }
    }
});

img2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
img2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tablet);
img2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        isClicked2=!isClicked2;
        if (isClicked2) {
            img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.tablet);
            start();
            stuff2 = "tablet";
           myList.add(stuff2);
        }else {
            img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.tablet);
           // sport2 = "";
            myList.remove(sport2);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10265352/pass-arraylist-from-activity-to-listfragment

Comment: you can also call method of fragment by activity, or activity - fragment.

Comment: @KrunalIndrodiya how can I do so ?

Comment: @HiteshMatnani Please check answer given by me. If any issues mention here.

Comment: @KrunalIndrodiya I had mention an error please go from it.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [Fragment arguments](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) here.

From Activity or where you instantiate your fragments or make a transaction:

```
 private void putList(List<String> list) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putStringArrayList("myList", new ArrayList<>(list));

        Fragment fragment = new MyFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    }
```

Inside each fragment:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    List<String> list = getArguments().getStringArrayList("myList");
}
```

Comment: My application is unfortunate stopped error coming on implementation of List<String> list = getArguments().getStringArrayList("myList");

Comment: @HiteshMatnani, post your error then. Code is fine.

Comment: When running application it is unfortunate stopped

Comment: I am coding like this -next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {{
Intent innext = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivitytabnew.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();bundle.putStringArrayList("my", myList);
FragmentPlayo fragment = new FragmentPlayo();
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
startActivity(innext);}});

Comment: @HiteshMatnani, because you do it wrong. The question is asking how to get data passed from Activity to a Fragment. But you start another Activity. Attach more sources.

Comment: why you need my more code it simple on click next button parse the value from Activity to fragment and let have an toast on fragment so it be tested

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
intent.putCharSequenceArrayListExtra(tag, arraylist);
```

and

```
getIntent().getExtras().getCharSequenceArrayList(tag);
```

Comment: Tanks!! I am using your answer but in putCharSequenceArrayListExtra it showing error - The method putCharSequenceArrayListExtra(String, ArrayList<CharSequence>) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (String, ArrayList<String>)

Comment: Sorry Use   putStringArrayListExtra(tag,array);  instead

Comment: When running application it is unfortunate stopped

Answer (score 0):

You can do this,

In fragment. Access Activity method by fragment.

```
ActivityName activityName=(ActivityName)getActivity();
if(activityName!=null){
    activityName.MethodOfActivityName();
}
```

In activity, Access Fragment method by Activity.

```
fragmentObject.MethodName();
```

Comment: Sorry your code I can not understand In your ans code where I am parsing the value of array-list

Comment: @HiteshMatnani, hi, you have to parse arrayList in method.
Mean MethodOfActivityName(arrayList) is method name.

Comment: My array list name is myArray. My activity name is MainActivity and fragment name is fragmentA where i wanna data can you now please tell me what to pleace where to place as per your method

Comment: @HiteshMatnani sorry for inconvenience.

MainActivity activityName=(MainActivity)getActivity();
if(activityName!=null){
    activityName.MethodOfActivityName(myArray);
}

Comment: and how to get the value ??

Comment: Fragment are supposed to be independent from everything, so it can be used in any activity as needed. This approach does not make that.

Answer (score 0):

In my case , I just used intent to share String Array from activity to fragment. That worked for me.

In Activity

```
 Intent send=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FragmentActivity.class);
                send.putExtra("array",TouristPlaces);
```

In Fragment under onCreateView..

```
Intent in=getActivity().getIntent();
    String [] ReceivedTouristPlaces=in.getStringArrayExtra("array");
```

Note: In my activity I used list view for my requirement, on click it sends data to fragment, which has a tab.